# Given the joint distribution of two random variables, compute the probability that one is less than the other?

Tags: probability, statistics, functions

Let $X$, $Y$ have the joint density function

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$$

Compute $P(X<Y)$.

I believe that I should set up a double integral over this function, like so:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^y\frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} dx dy$$

However, I do not get a convergent integral like I should. My work is shown below:

When I first integrate with respect to x, I get:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {1}{(4\pi*y)} dy$$ and after solving this integral, I get $$-\frac {ln(y)}{4\pi} $$ evaluated from $-{\infty}$ to $\infty$, which doesn't give me a conclusive result.

Thoughts?

Comment: "When I first integrate with respect to x, I get..." well, not at all what you wrote in your question. You might want to ponder this step again.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts: *separable* and *symmetric*

- $\frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(x^2)/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(y^2)/2}$
- $\frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} = \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-(y^2+x^2)/2}$

Comment: Has my double integral been set up correctly, then?

Comment: Yes, though I do not see why you say "I do not get a convergent integral"

Comment: When I first integrate with respect to dx, I get:

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^y\frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(y^2)/2} \Phi(y)$ which, while it may not have a closed form because $\Phi(y)$ does not, is certainly a real number for any real $y$; it is not $\dfrac {1}{(4\pi*y)}$. But doing the two integrals is not the easiest approach.

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment and look at the edits I have made to the original post. Do you see any error in my work? I'm guessing something is going wrong when I am doing the integration.

Comment: $\dfrac {1}{(4\pi*y)}$ is not correct for the first integral

Comment: It seems that a double integral is not a feasible way to solve this problem. Is there a more intuitive way to look at it?

Comment: Consider my second thought. What might be the relationships between $\Pr(X \lt Y)$ and $\Pr(Y \lt X)$ be?  If you add them? If you subtract them?

Comment: I think that $Pr(X<Y)$ and $Pr(Y<X)$ must be equal... and adding them together would give me one, while subtracting would give me zero...

Comment: So if $p+p=1$, then what is $p$?

Comment: Ah, so p = 1/2! Thanks!

Comment: Would the answer be any different if the question asked for "less than or equal to"?

Comment: No - not with a continuous case like this, as the probability of equality is zero.

Answer (score 1):

By Symmetry and Seperability, the two Random Variables $X$ and $Y$ are Independent.So

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}},x \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}},y \in \mathbb{R}$$ Now

$$P(X<Y)=\int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty}P(X<y/Y=y)f_Y(y)dy$$ $\implies$
$$P(X<Y)=\int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{x=-\infty}^{y}f_X(x)dx\right)f_Y(y)dy$$ $\implies$

$$P(X<Y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{x=-\infty}^{y}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx\right)e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy$$ $\implies$

$$P(X<Y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{x=-y}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx\right)e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy$$ $\implies$

$$P(X<Y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} Q(-y)e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy$$ $\implies$

$$P(X<Y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} Q(y)e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{0}Q(y)e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}+\int_{0}^{\infty}Q(y)e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}Q(-y)e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}+\int_{0}^{\infty}Q(y)e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}\right)$$ But $$Q(y)+Q(-y)=1$$ $\implies$

$$P(X<Y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that the standard bivariate normal random variable is radially symmetric about the origin.  That's a pretty big clue, since it means that the probability that a point lying below the line y = x equals the probability of lying below the line y = 0 equals 1/2.

If you want more analysis and less geometry, try converting to polar coordinates.  We have $(X,Y) \sim N_{0,1}$, and we define:

$$R^2 = X^2 + Y^2$$

and

$$\tan \Theta = \frac{Y}{X}$$

The joint density of $R^2$ and $\Theta$ is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}$$

for $0 \leq r^2$ and $0 \leq \Theta \leq 2\pi$.  In particular, they are independent, $R^2$ is exponentially distributed, and $\Theta$ is uniform on $[0,2\pi]$.  Marginalize on $R^2$ and integrate from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{5\pi}{4}$.